# Logic of numerical series

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

One of our colleagues has written a numerical series to the whiteboard in our breakroom. Nobody until now could solve the logic behind this series:

```
1, 14, 3, -8, 27, 41, -91, 33, ...
```

Can anybody say how this series is continued and whats the logic to calculate it?

It's enough to drive one to despair.

Comment: was there supposed to be a _logic_ behind this series?

Comment: @Sid Yes, the 33 has been added later to make more 'easier'.

Comment: The Online Encyclopedia of Sequences does not have your sequence!

Comment: There are at least two good reasons that the next term is 42.

Comment: @gammatester can you state your assumption?

Comment: @gammatester is there any mathematical logic behind your guess? ;)

Comment: @sebastian: Be patient! First: There is exactly one polynomial of degree 8 interpolating the points $(1,1),  (2,14), (3,3), (4,-8), (5,27), (6,41), (7,-91), (8,33), (9,42);\;$ and second and more important 
*42 is the answer to the great question of Life, The Universe, And Everything ...!* :)

Comment: @gammatester ;) okay, thank you, but there has to be one other solution.

Comment: @gammatester I don't think this is the great question of Life, The Universe, And Everything :P

Comment: @Wonder: Maybe, chances are not very high; but unfortunately the 'computer'
which should compute the question was destroyed a little bit too early.

Comment: I hope that guy verfied his rule.

Comment: what language are you speaking with you colleague? (could be related to the way of writing the number in your language)

Comment: Ask the person to write out 100 terms, then when they least expected it, tie up & blindfold them and ask them to use that logic to calculate the sequences again. 3 things can be learnt from the attempt: (a) if the person really have a logic to it instead of just lying; (b) how much time taken to calculate the number at a random location in the sequence, which might indicate which process is used to calculate; (c) whether "driven to despair by unfathomable integers sequence" defense is acceptable to the jury of your peers.

Comment: Could be his phone number, or just random numbers... the problem is that there are infinite possibilities of a "rule", and Kolmogorov complexity problem is undecidable, so you can't actually know the solution you found was optimal.

Comment: Define $f(x)=\frac{30640536597481}{36571315854904871040} x^6 + \frac{4212281765921}{406347953943387456} x^5 - \frac{283080505675367}{61156046580108480} x^4 + \frac{75527336124312005}{609521930915081184} x^3 - \frac{20018723545003549}{122312093160216960} x^2 - \frac{43620987074882501}{3705300491884992} x + \frac{1143671622098613}{44299227492520}$. $f(1)=14$, $f(14)=3$,...

Answer (score 1):

Last week, I posted this answer:

> You ask, "Can anybody say how this series is continued and what's the logic to calculate it?"
>
> The answer is yes; the colleague who wrote it on the whiteboard can do both of those things.

That answer was deleted by a moderator.

Since then, no one here has been able to say how the series is continued, etc. (as OP correctly rejects anything based on Lagrange interpolation). So I think it's time to post a modified version of my deleted answer:

> The answer is yes; **only** the colleague who wrote it on the whiteboard can do both of those things.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lagarange's Law(Method of finite difference)
Write them like this:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
1&14&3&-8&27&41&-91&33&\Delta^0\\
(-)&1&14&3&-8&27&41&-91\\\hline
..&13&-11&-11&35&14&-132&124&\Delta^1\\
...&(-)&13&-11&-11&35&14&-132\\\hline
...&...&-24&...&...&...&...&...&\Delta^2
\end{array}$$
Now you can write the series as :
$$t_n=\binom {n-1}0\Delta^0 t_1+\binom {n-1}1\Delta^1 t_1+\binom {n-1}2\Delta^2 t_1+\cdots\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom {n-1}k\Delta^k t_1+$$
<sub>which can be proved by mathematical induction</sub>
<sub>Also take $\binom nr=0 ,\text{ for } r<0$</sub>

where, $\Delta^rt_1$ is the first term of r<sup>th</sup> difference, for e.g.
$$\Delta^0t_1=1,\Delta^1t_1=13,\Delta^2t_1=-24\cdots$$

---

<sub>Actually this method(as in here) is just a way of interpolation with the given data, if you use 8 terms in the formula you get eight terms correct, if for example a series of 2,4,6,8... ;the $\Delta^1 t_1=2$ and further all differences are zero so it correctly forms the function $2\times\binom {n-1}0+2\times\binom{n-1}1=2n$; this method can tell all terms if we had other terms too or until some level of difference became $0${or a special series}.</sub>

Comment: If this is the correct approach, then we should be able to use the beginning portion of the sequence (up to -91) to obtain the "extra" term 33 which was written down later to make the problem easier. But this approach give -307 instead.

Comment: no you need to consider 33 too for this method

Comment: Several days ago, the OP has told us the last term $33$ is not there in the beginning, the OP's colleague write down $33$ later to make the problem easier. This means if the OP's colleague is not lying nor making any mistake and the sequence does have a logic behind, it can be deduced from the initial portion of the sequence w/o using the term $33$.

Comment: see my edit,i.e. end of post